# How can I save a .html file as an email template file for MS Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, html-mail

I have MS Outlook 365. I've created a HTML file I wish to use as an email template. For the life of me I cannot figure out how to do this.

I've tried searching online but all the existing tutorials deal with Outlook 2010 or 2013 or deal with creating a template from an existing plain text email.

Would anyone know how to achieve this or know of any tutorials that can help guide me?

Answer (score 5):

I have found [this](http://www.visuallizard.com/blog/2013/10/25/outlook-email-templates) tutorial:

- Step 1: [Creating your HTML template](http://www.visuallizard.com/blog/2012/04/27/html-email-specs-update)
- Step 2: Getting your template into Outlook

> Once you've built your email template as an HTML document with all of
>   its images and styles you'll need to open that HTML template in
>   Internet Explorer. Once you have it displaying in IE you'll need to
>   send it to Outlook. You can do this by opening IE's File menu and
>   selecting Send. Hovering the Send option will give you the option of
>   sending it as an email. Clicking this will open your new template in
>   an Outlook Email window.

- Step 3: Saving your template

The point / pitfall is in step 3:

> First you must File > Save. **Wait, you're not done**. Once you've
>   saved the email you can then save the email template. Now you must
>   File > Save As. Select the save as Outlook Template option in the
>   selection list that appears in the dialogue that opens. You have now
>   saved your template and can now use it.

Comment: Thanks, but I am stuck at Step 2. Currently I have my HTML file completely separate and independent of Outlook. Cant figure out how to make it an html email in Outlook let alone an template.

Comment: Any tutorial for Office 2013 applies to Office 365.  Have you tried to follow them? **"open that HTML template in Internet Explorer. Once you have it displaying in IE you'll need to send it to Outlook. You can do this by opening IE's File menu and selecting Send. Hovering the Send option will give you the option of sending it as an email. Clicking this will open your new template in an Outlook Email window."** - This applies to any version of Outlook.  There are multiple teirs of Office 365, you do have a desktop client, right?

Comment: No Send option in IE11 Windows 10...

Comment: To find the send option in IE11, Win10, open the webpage, go to file in the browser (to get file menu click alt, it should auto pop up). Send is the 4th option from the bottom.

Also ensure you are using IE11, not edge. I can't find the send option in edge... yet :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe the only convenient way to use HTML templates for Outlook messages is to use VBA macro. For example (to get the template from D:\Template.html):

```
Sub SetHTMLBody()
    Open "D:\Template.html" For Input As #1
    ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.HTMLBody = Input$(LOF(1), 1)
    Close #1
End Sub
```

You can place the button that runs the script on Outlook message window's ribbon and then fill the message HTML text from the template with a single click of a button.

Comment: This takes a bit more set up (such as turning on the dev bar and creating the macro) but also works as well as the above answer. Maybe better, in some scenarios I have not yet encountered.

Comment: I prefer this answer to duDE's because it is programmatic and easier to automate.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for each new email or on each reply?

Comment: Oh look http://qlockwork.com/timetrackingthoughts/2012/10/microsoft-outlook-2010-tips-how-to-run-a-vba-macro-on-new-emails/ this might enhance your already good answer :)